# SNMPv3 can snmpwalk with noAuthNoPriv for user with authPriv

Tags: snmp, network-protocols, net-snmp

I defined in my model an snmp v3 user `user1` with authPriv.
It has auth password and priv password.

I succeed `snmpwalk` on my model with the following line:

```
snmpwalk -v3 -u user1 -l authPriv -a SHA -A 12345678 -x DES -X 123456789 localhost:7999 1.3.6.1.4.1.89898
```

The problem is that I also succeed `snmpwalk` without auto and priv:

```
snmpwalk -v3 -u user1 -l noAuthNoPriv localhost:7999 1.3.6.1.4.1.89898
```

I couldn't understand why the `snmpwalk` without password works.

I want to be able to define a user with `authPriv` and with `noAuthNoPriv`, and when someone tries to `snmpwalk` without the correct password of the `authPriv` user he should fails.

When I use

```
snmpwalk -v3 -u user1 -l authPriv ...
```

with incorrect password there's an access denied.

This is my `vacmAccessTable`:

```
<vacmAccessTable>

<!-- The group 'all-rights' has full access to everything -->

<vacmAccessEntry>
  <vacmGroupName>all-rights</vacmGroupName>
  <vacmAccessContextPrefix></vacmAccessContextPrefix>
  <vacmAccessSecurityModel>3</vacmAccessSecurityModel>
  <vacmAccessSecurityLevel>noAuthNoPriv</vacmAccessSecurityLevel>
  <vacmAccessContextMatch>exact</vacmAccessContextMatch>
  <vacmAccessReadViewName>internet</vacmAccessReadViewName>
  <vacmAccessWriteViewName>internet</vacmAccessWriteViewName>
  <vacmAccessNotifyViewName>internet</vacmAccessNotifyViewName>
</vacmAccessEntry>

<vacmAccessEntry>
  <vacmGroupName>all-rights</vacmGroupName>
  <vacmAccessContextPrefix></vacmAccessContextPrefix>
  <vacmAccessSecurityModel>3</vacmAccessSecurityModel>
  <vacmAccessSecurityLevel>authNoPriv</vacmAccessSecurityLevel>
  <vacmAccessContextMatch>exact</vacmAccessContextMatch>
  <vacmAccessReadViewName>internet</vacmAccessReadViewName>
  <vacmAccessWriteViewName>internet</vacmAccessWriteViewName>
  <vacmAccessNotifyViewName>internet</vacmAccessNotifyViewName>
</vacmAccessEntry>

<vacmAccessEntry>
<vacmGroupName>all-rights</vacmGroupName>
  <vacmAccessContextPrefix></vacmAccessContextPrefix>
  <vacmAccessSecurityModel>3</vacmAccessSecurityModel>
  <vacmAccessSecurityLevel>authPriv</vacmAccessSecurityLevel>
  <vacmAccessContextMatch>exact</vacmAccessContextMatch>
  <vacmAccessReadViewName>internet</vacmAccessReadViewName>
  <vacmAccessWriteViewName>internet</vacmAccessWriteViewName>
  <vacmAccessNotifyViewName>internet</vacmAccessNotifyViewName>
</vacmAccessEntry>
```

Comment: I don't think your VACM setting is the right place. Have you checked Net-SNMP doc?

Comment: I haven't checked it. Could you please point me to which section I should look at?

Comment: Ask Google. I only remember it is in a typical config file.

Comment: I got confused - do you mean a typical config file of snmpwalk? or a config file in my snmp configuration?

Comment: a config file for snmpd. On the snmpwalk side you can do anything, but it should be the agent side who denies the access.